# Progressbar with Paging library android

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-architecture-lifecycle, android-paging

I'm looking to use the new architecture component "Paging Library" https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging.html in my app where it fetches data from server and displays in a recyclerview.

The paging library is a good addition and helps to manage paginating the content. I've checked all the samples and they work fine. But one requirement I have is that when we scroll to the end of recyclerview and the next page starts loading (managed by the Paging Library) I need to show a progress bar row at the bottom.

I know how to do this with recyclerview scroll listeners and 2 view types. But the solution I'm seeking is how to do this with the "Paging Library". It has option to enable place holders which is not what I want.

Any help on this is highly appreciated.

Comment: Please post links to samples (that uses network api/not database)

Comment: @Auct hi, check this one http://androidkt.com/rest-api-pagination-paging-library/

Comment: @Alex y I'm used patially this, thought there was some more stuff on that. Anyway when I turn off/on internet it won't scroll more :( So I end up with continue using hacks with scrollListener

Comment: @AucT You can call `invalidate()` method for your `DataSource` when network state will changed. So after invalidating your `DataSource`, `LivePagedListProvider` will create a new instance of `DataSource` with saving your `RecyclerView` position state (if you will use Adapter from Paging Library).

Comment: Did you find any proper solution? @Sreekanth

Comment: Hello, did you find an answer to this?

Answer (score -1):

if I right understand you use custom TiledDataSource, so from `loadRange(int, int)` you can send signal to UI thread about progress starting, and in your observer stop progressBar showing.